# Adding a model in Django Admin to the User/Group models?

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django admin site has Authentication and Authorization which has users and groups. When we add models, they are displayed below this. Is it possible to add a model immediately below Groups, Users? And how can we change the existing names?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, takes some work, and it's going to trigger some warning in Django 1.8. But this is basically what you do:

Suppose you have an application `myauth` that will override the default `django.contrib.auth` application...

In `myauth/models.py` do this:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group


class ExtraModel(models.Model):
    ...
```

`ExtraModel` is the model you want to add.

In `myauth/__init__.py` do this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class OverrideAuthConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'auth'
    verbose_name = "New User and Authentication"

default_app_config = 'auth.OverrideAuthConfig'
```

In `myauth/admin.py` do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User, Group, ExtraModel

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Group)
admin.site.register(ExtraModel)
```

And in your `settings.py`, within `INSTALLED_APPS` comment out the line:

```
...
#'django.contrib.auth',
...
```

and just add your application:

```
...
'myauth',
...
```

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 0):

Try to override admin `index` template ...

change this `{% for app in app_list %}` to `{% for app in app_list reversed %}` or sort it in some custom way ...

---

### EDIT

seems I've found easier solution :)

https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder