# Changing the group of a model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For whatever reason I have three models related to authentication, but in Django Admin they show up in two different groups. For example:

```
AUTHORIZATION
-------------
Security Questions
Users

AUTHORIZATION AND AUTHENTICATION
--------------------------------
Groups
```

Seems like they should be under one group and I would like to move them to be under one group.

I came across this Q/A from a few years ago:

[Adding a model in Django Admin to the User/Group models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340887/adding-a-model-in-django-admin-to-the-user-group-models)

Wonder if there is an easier way now in Django 1.11 like using a `class Meta:` in the model or in `admin.py`. Looking through the documentation and haven't come across anything yet.

Comment: you can use proxy model that will help for show your model in different app in admin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually had to combine what both Mohammad and NeErAj suggested.

When I tried to move `Groups` to the `Authorization` section, which is an app containing a custom `User` model, it created duplicates of the Groups. Django still wanted to insert the default `auth_group` which I couldn't figure out how to get rid of.

```
# ./models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Group(Group):
    pass

    class Meta:
    app_label = 'authentication'
```

---

```
# ./admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User, SecurityQuestions, Group

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(SecurityQuestions)
admin.site.register(Group)
```

---

```
AUTHORIZATION
-------------
Groups
Security Questions
Users

AUTHORIZATION AND AUTHENTICATION
--------------------------------
Groups
```

Since I was using a custom `User` model, I figured it would be easier to move them to `app_label = 'auth'`. That way I wouldn't have to fight with the default `auth_group`. Ended up doing the following:

```
# ./models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Users'

class SecurityQuestions(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
        db_table = 'Security_Questions'
        verbose_name = 'Security Question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Security Questions'

 class ProxyUser(User):
     pass

     class Meta:
         app_label = 'auth'
         proxy = True
         verbose_name = 'User'
         verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

---

```
# ./admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User, SecurityQuestions, ProxyUser

admin.site.register(ProxyUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(SecurityQuestions)
```

This got everything to look like:

```
AUTHORIZATION AND AUTHENTICATION
--------------------------------
Groups
Security Questions
Users
```

Comment: This is the best solution found but it creates a migration file at contrib\auth\migrations directory. You have to delete it to avoid creation in other projects.

Comment: I did not have any issues with a migration file being created using Django v2.2.4. Great approach!

Comment: Indeed it creates a migration file in contrib\auth\migrations (in the Django library itself). At least this is true for Django 3.0.7. So this is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use the [django-modeladmin-reorder](https://github.com/mishbahr/django-modeladmin-reorder): it allows you to reorder and merge apps in the admin site.

Here is the configuration that you'd need for this particular example:

```py
ADMIN_REORDER = [
    {
        'app': 'auth',
        'models': [
            'my_custom_auth_app.User',
            'my_custom_auth_app.SecurityQuestions',
            'auth.Group',
        ]
    }
]
```

Behind the scenes, this app uses a middleware that changes the `app_list` context when rendering the admin templates.

Comment: Is there any maintained package similar to this?

Answer (score 2):

To move groups in to custom models in admin

*inspired by the accepted answer*

```py
#  apps/account/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Roles(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = verbose_name_plural = 'Roles'
```

```py
#  apps/account/admins.py

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Roles)
```

[image]

Comment: Easy steps. Great!!