# django admin move auth models to another section

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I'm using **Django 2.x**

I have created a custom user model by extending the AbstractModel in `authentication` application

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

and updated in settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
```

This has resulted in two sections in the admin panel. One section **authentication** contains **User** model while default **Authentication and Authorization** contain only **Group** model.

I want to move either **User** to **Authentication and Authorization** or **Group** to **Authentication** so that both models could be together in a section.

For that, I have added this in the `authentication.admin.py`

```
apps.get_model('auth.Group')._meta.app_label = 'authentication'
```

To move **Group** to **Authentication**.

After running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

It generates migration in the `auth` app of django

```
Migrations for 'auth':
  /Users/anuj/.local/share/virtualenvs/originor_py-Vd6fDdN7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_auto_20190220_0238.py
    - Remove field permissions from group
    - Alter field groups on user
    - Delete model Group
```

And on migrating the migrations `./manage.py migrate`, it gives error as

```
ValueError: The field auth.User.groups was declared with a lazy reference to 'authentication.group', but app 'authentication' doesn't provide model 'group'.
```

**How can I move `Group` model to another section in the Django admin?

Do I need to create custom Group model?**

Comment: I think your issue is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673134/changing-the-group-of-a-model-in-django-admin

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden `AbstractUser` which inherits `AbstractBaseUser` and **`PermissionsMixin`** as below
`class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):`

You could see `groups` attribute in `django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin`

```
class PermissionsMixin(models.Model):
    """
    A mixin class that adds the fields and methods necessary to support
    Django's Group and Permission model using the ModelBackend.
    """
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    ...
```

Create `CustomGroup` model and add that model to `groups` attribute as follow.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomGroup,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'
        ),
        related_name="user_set",
        related_query_name="user",
    )
    ...
```

> This would help you to override default `Group` model altered with your `CustomGroup` model

Comment: But I do not want to override default group and just want to put it in a different section in the Django Admin panel.